# Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings; Message: ReferenceError: xxx is not defined;

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

This is my first use of Knockout.js.

I don't understand why I have this problem.

**Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: DataPrevista is not defined;
Bindings value: value:DataPrevista, namePath: true**

I wish anyone help me.

This is my code:

View

```
                    <div>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cliente)
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cliente.Codigo, new SelectList(Model.ClientesSelecionaveis, "Value", "Text", Model.Cliente), new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Funcionario)
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Funcionario.Codigo, new SelectList(Model.FuncionariosSelecionaveis, "Value", "Text", Model.Cliente), new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div style="margin:30px 0;">
                            <input type="button" value="Adicionar Agendamento" data-bind="click: addAgendamento" class="btn btn-success" />
                            <input type="button" value="Remover Agendamento" data-bind="click: removeAgendamento" class="btn btn-danger" />
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="page-header">Agendamentos</h4>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Agendamentos)
                    </fieldset>
                    <p style="margin:30px 0;">
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-info" />
                        @Html.ActionLink("Listar", "Index")
                    </p>
```

Editor Template

```
<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataPrevista)
</div> 
   <div>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataPrevista, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: dataPrevista, namePath: true" })
 </div>

  <div>
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InicioPrevisto)
    </div>
   <div>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InicioPrevisto, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: inicioPrevisto, namePath: true" })
     </div>

   <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FimPrevisto)
   </div>
   <div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FimPrevisto, new { @class = "form-control",      data_bind = "value: fimPrevisto, namePath: true" })
   </div>

  <div>
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrasladoPrevisto)
  </div>
   <div>
@ Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TrasladoPrevisto, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: trasladoPrevisto, namePath: true" })
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function createViewModel() {

    var createAgendamento = function () {
        return {
            dataPrevista: ko.observable(),
            inicioPrevisto: ko.observable(),
            fimPrevisto: ko.observable(),
            trasladoPrevisto: ko.observable()
        };
    };

    var addAgendamento = function () {
        agendamentos.push(createAgendamento());
    };

    var removeAgendamento = function () {
        agendamentos.pop();
    };

    var cliente = ko.observable();
    var funcionario = ko.observable();
    var agendamentos = ko.observableArray([createAgendamento()]);

    return {
        cliente: cliente,
        funcionario: funcionario,
        agendamentos: agendamentos,
        addAgendamento: addAgendamento,
        removeAgendamento: removeAgendamento
    };
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = createViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: "DataPrevista is not defined". So somewhere in your html you have a binding `data-bind="value:DataPrevista"` but your javascript viewmodel does not have this property. However in the code in your question there is `DataPrevista` so you have posted the wrong code... so nobody will tell you how to fix this.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your data syntax is incorrect.  It should be `data-bind` not `data_bind`

See Knockout documentation: [binding syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html)

Also `dataPrevista` is a nested observable within your view model, so you would need to reference it like this.

```
data-bind="value: agendamentos.dataPrevista"
```